# Virtual host - Not Found

Tags: apache, xampp, virtual, host

I wolud like to use virtual host on Apache 2.4
I use Xampp and I will have more site so on it.
I have already read some guide and I have edit my httpd.config

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and the Load

also my defalut port in busy, so I have set

```
Listen 8080
```

After that I edit my httpd-vhosts.conf in this way

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
  <VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName sample.locl
    DocumentRoot "C:\wwww\sample"
    <Directory "C:\wwww\sample">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted              
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName sample2.locl
    DocumentRoot "C:\wwww\sample2"
    <Directory "C:\wwww\sample2">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted              
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

N.B. my site is in C:/www/sample and c:/www/sample2 and my xampp in in c:/xampp.

At the end I edit my host in system32 with

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 sample
127.0.0.1 sample2
```

Now I have 404 error, neither when I wrote: "localhost" in my url browser.

If i Understand how it work I suppose that when i write localhost it will be redirect to C:\xampp\htdocs and so I should see my xampp page but it's not so.. where did I go wrong?

### I always recive

Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the port to the url you wrote in the browser? localhost:8080

Comment: Yes, if i wrote the complete url.. like http://localhost:8080/xampp/ it goes.. but in this way i can't keep more than ine site at a time

Comment: Did you try `sample.locl:8080`?

Comment: Access denied
error 403.. what mean? 
I have already work on it when it was in htdocs